# How to draw tangent to two touching circles and marking the points

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-collection, circles

This question may seem repetitive to many, but as I am very new to Latex, even after reading many posts, could not get to draw what I wanted, so asking.
I want to draw as the following.
[image]

I have written the following code, Please help further.

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}                       % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
\geometry{letterpaper}                          % ... or a4paper or a5paper or ... 
\geometry{landscape}  
\usepackage{tikz}   % TeX will automatically convert eps --> pdf in pdflatex    
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}  
\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) circle(2) node [left] {P};
\draw (3.5,0) circle(1.5) node [below] {Q};
\draw (0,0) -- (14,0) node [right] {O};

\newcommand*{\Radius}{2cm}%
   \coordinate (Origin) at (0,0);
   \coordinate (O) at (14,0);% External point

\tkzDrawCircle[R](Origin,\Radius)
   \tkzTangent[from with R= O](Origin,\Radius)  \tkzGetPoints{R}{I} 

   \tkzDrawSegments[ultra thick](O,R)% First tangent
   \tkzDrawSegments[ultra thick](O,I)% Second tangent
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). Your code is not compilable as it is.

Comment: What is it you still want to do with the figure? It looks fine already. Do you want to put the labels?

Comment: Yes,I want the labels and the tangents to extend a bit further after touching the big circle..

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I give my personal answer because It's preferable to avoid to mix syntaxes ( tikz and euclide ) and I added some remarks. I take big parts from hpesoj626's answer.

Firstly, I prefer to use several parts in my code, I created *tkz-euclide* to do this: definition, calculations, drawings and labels. If you study tikz enough, you will be able to use only tikz and to put *tkz-euclide* in the trash.

**Remarks about definitions**

1. You can use `coordinate` here from tikz but if you use another system of coordinates from tkz then you can go down some complications.
2. `\pgfmathsetmacro` is more `tikzien` but  you need to add the unity after

**Remarks about calculations** : none it's fine

**Remarks about drawings :**

1. In general with *tkz-euclide* macros come by pair like `\tkzDrawSegment` and `\tkzDrawSegments`. The second is to draw several objects with the same options but if you need specific options, then you need to use the first form.
2. option `add`. I added to *tkz-euclide* the possibility to use tikz option but I added  somme specific option that I created. You can use `add = n and m` to extend a line (n and m are a percent of the length of the line. I prefer this possibility because it's easy to add  half of a line or to double the line.

**Remarks about labels :**

The same remarks about the pair of macros. You can add labels with general options or with specific ones.

**Conclusion** *tkz-euclide* is useful only if you need to draw several pictures and if you want to write rapidly your code but for one picture, I think it's preferable to study tikz.
With *tkz-euclide* you need to know some options from tikz.

So a  *tkz-euclide* solution is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8]

% definitions
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){Origin}
\tkzDefPoint(3.5,0){Q}
\tkzDefPoint(14,0){O}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Radius}{2}

% calculations
\tkzTangent[from with R = O](Origin,\Radius cm)  \tkzGetPoints{R}{I} 
\tkzInterLC[R](Q,Origin)(Q,1.5cm) \tkzGetPoints{M}{N}
\tkzTangent[from=O](Q,M) \tkzGetPoints{S}{II}

% drawing
\tkzDrawCircle[R](Origin,\Radius cm)
\tkzDrawCircle(Q,M)
\tkzDrawSegments[ultra thick,orange,add = 0 and .2](O,R O,I)
\tkzDrawSegments[thick,gray](Origin,O)
\tkzDrawPoints(Origin,O,Q,R,I,II,S)

% labels
\tkzLabelPoints(R,S,Q,I,II,O)
\tkzLabelPoint[below right](Origin){$P$}
\tkzLabelPoints[above,text=red](R,S)
\tkzLabelPoints[above,text=blue](I,II)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would you kindly explain “what” and “how” of the code below `calculations`? (For example: What is `R` in `\tkzDrawCircle[R]`, and what does `\tkzTangent[from with R = O]` do?

Answer (score 9):

You can get the tangents to extend by adding `shorten >=<negative length>`, and use the `intersections` library to locate the points of intersection and add the appropriate labels:

[image]

If you use `\coordinate`s for the poitns then using a `\foreach` is a convienent way to mark each of the points.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}                       % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
\geometry{letterpaper}                          % ... or a4paper or a5paper or ... 
\geometry{landscape}  
\usepackage{tikz}   % TeX will automatically convert eps --> pdf in pdflatex    
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}  
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}  
\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\newcommand*{\Radius}{2cm}%
   \coordinate (Origin) at (0,0);
   \coordinate (OriginQ) at (3.5,0);
   \coordinate (O) at (14,0);% External point


\draw [name path global=circle P] (Origin)  circle(2.0) node [left]  {P};
\draw [name path global=circle Q] (OriginQ) circle(1.5) node [below] {Q};
\draw (Origin) -- (14,0) node [right] {O};



\tkzDrawCircle[R](Origin,\Radius)
   \tkzTangent[from with R= O](Origin,\Radius)  \tkzGetPoints{R}{I} 

   \tkzDrawSegments[ultra thick, blue, shorten >=-2.5cm, name path global=top tangent](O,R)% First tangent
   \tkzDrawSegments[ultra thick, red, shorten >=-2.5cm, name path global=bottom tangent](O,I)% Second tangent


\path [name intersections={of=circle P and top tangent, by=circlePTop}];
\node [above] at (circlePTop) {$R$};

\path [name intersections={of=circle Q and top tangent, by=circleQTop}];
\node [above] at (circleQTop) {$S$};

\path [name intersections={of=circle P and bottom tangent, by=circlePBot}];
\node [below] at (circlePBot) {$I$};

\path [name intersections={of=circle Q and bottom tangent, by=circleQBot}];
\node [below] at (circleQBot) {$II$};

\foreach \Point in {circlePTop, circleQTop, circlePBot, circleQBot, Origin, OriginQ} {
    \draw [fill=gray, draw=black] (\Point) circle (2.5pt);
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

[image]

Here is an attempt trying to stick closely to `tkz-euclide` commands.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tkzDefPoint(0,0){Origin}
\tkzDefPoint(3.5,0){Q}
\tkzDefPoint(14,0){O}

\node [left] at (Origin) {$P$};
\node [right] at (O) {$O$};

\newcommand*{\Radius}{2cm}%

\tkzDrawCircle[R](Origin,\Radius)
\tkzTangent[from with R= O](Origin,\Radius)  \tkzGetPoints{R}{I} 
\tkzLabelPoints(R,I,Q)
\node [above, red] at (R) {$R$};

\tkzInterLC[R](Q,Origin)(Q,1.5cm) \tkzGetPoints{M}{N}
\tkzDrawCircle(Q,M)

\tkzTangent[from=O](Q,M) \tkzGetPoints{S}{II}
\node [above] at (S) {$S$};
\node [below] at (II) {$II$};

\tkzDrawSegments[ultra thick,orange,shorten >=-1cm](O,R)% First tangent
\tkzDrawSegments[ultra thick,orange,shorten >=-1cm](O,I)% Second tangent
\tkzDrawSegments[thick,gray](Origin,O)

\tkzDrawPoints(Origin,O,Q,R,I,II,S)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You can also use  regular `tikz` commands, so instead of writing `\tkzLabelPoints(R)` you can also write `\node [above, red] at (R) {$R$};`.

Comment: Do you know if there English documentation available yet for `tkz-euclide`?

Comment: Thanks.. @Peter : No, I haven't found English documentation for tkz-euclide?

Comment: @PeterGrill Afaik, There is none. I just follow the  examples. If I only know French, I would offer to help Alain Matthes with the translation.

Comment: Yes a translation would be perhaps useful but my english is not very fine. I don't know if there are a lot of users. Perhaps it's preferable to recommend to study tikz. The different syntax is a big problem nd perhaps it's a wrong way ...

Answer (score 5):

run with `xelatex`. All important points are marked as nodes, see documentation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-4,-2)(5,3)
\pscircle*[linecolor=red!30!white!100](0,0){1}
\pscircle*[linecolor=green!30!white!100](3,0){2}
\psCircleTangents(0,0){1}(3,0){2}% coordinates/radius of the 2 circles
\pcline[nodesep=-1cm,linecolor=blue](CircleTO1)(CircleTC2)
\pcline[nodesep=-1cm,linecolor=blue](CircleTO3)(CircleTC2)
\psdots(CircleTC2)(CircleTO1)(CircleTO2)(CircleTO3)(CircleTO4)
\uput[-90](CircleTC2){TC2}
\uput[-80](CircleTO1){TO1}\uput[45](CircleTO2){TO2}
\uput[150](CircleTO3){TO3}\uput[-45](CircleTO4){TO4}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

With PSTricks.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\newpsstyle{N}{PointName=none,PointSymbol=none}
\newpsstyle{A}{PointNameA=,PointSymbolA=none}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(7,3)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={180,-45}](0,0){P}(3.5,0){Q}
    \pstGeonode[style=N](2.5,0){T}
    \pstCircleOA{P}{T}
    \pstCircleOA{Q}{T}
    \pstMiddleAB[style=N]{P}{Q}{M}
    \pstInterLC[style=N,Radius=\pstDistAB{T}{Q}]{P}{Q}{P}{}{LC1}{LC2}
    \pstInterCC[style=N,RadiusA=\pstDistAB{T}{LC2}]{P}{}{M}{P}{CC1}{CC2}
    \pstInterLC[style=A,PosAngleB=90]{P}{CC1}{P}{T}{LC3}{R}
    \pstTranslation[PosAngle=90]{CC1}{R}{Q}[S]
    \pstInterLL{R}{S}{P}{Q}{O}
    \pstLineAB[nodesepA=-1]{R}{O}
    \pstOrtSym[PosAngle=-90]{P}{Q}{R,S}[I,II]
    \pstLineAB[nodesepA=-1]{I}{O}
    \pstLineAB{P}{O}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### A funny "bug/feature" found:

Normally node label can be hidden by passing `none` to `PointName`. However, `PointNameA` cannot be set to `none` to hide its label. But it accepts nothing or `{}` instead.

### Animated

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl,multido}
\newpsstyle{N}{PointName=none,PointSymbol=none}
\newpsstyle{A}{PointNameA=,PointSymbolA=none}

\def\Picture#1{%
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(15,3)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={180,-45}](0,0){P}(3.5,0){Q}
    \pstGeonode[style=N](#1,0){T}
    \pstCircleOA{P}{T}
    \pstCircleOA{Q}{T}
    \pstMiddleAB[style=N]{P}{Q}{M}
    \pstInterLC[style=N,Radius=\pstDistAB{T}{Q}]{P}{Q}{P}{}{LC1}{LC2}
    \pstInterCC[style=N,RadiusA=\pstDistAB{T}{LC2}]{P}{}{M}{P}{CC1}{CC2}
    \pstInterLC[style=A,PosAngleB=90]{P}{CC1}{P}{T}{LC3}{R}
    \pstTranslation[PosAngle=90]{CC1}{R}{Q}[S]
    \pstInterLL{R}{S}{P}{Q}{O}
    \pstLineAB[nodesepA=-1]{R}{O}
    \pstOrtSym[PosAngle=-90]{P}{Q}{R,S}[I,II]
    \pstLineAB[nodesepA=-1]{I}{O}
    \pstLineAB{P}{O}
\end{pspicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\multido{\n=2.0+0.1}{10}{\Picture{\n}}
\multido{\n=2.8+-0.1}{8}{\Picture{\n}}
\end{document}
```