# Draw a tangent of a circle in the form of ray

Tags: tkz-euclide

Reference:
[How to draw tangent to two touching circles and marking the points](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103727/how-to-draw-tangent-to-two-touching-circles-and-marking-the-points)

With reference to above link I am trying to make the below figure. But I am not able to make the parts added in the figure by red color. Furthermore I want to draw two right angle marks at points R and I.
Please help me.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\Huge
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8]

\tkzDefPoint(0,0){Origin}
\tkzDefPoint(12,0){O}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Radius}{4}

\tkzTangent[from with R = O](Origin,\Radius cm)  \tkzGetPoints{R}{I} 

\tkzDrawCircle[R](Origin,\Radius cm)

\tkzDrawSegments[thick,black,add = 0 and .4](O,R O,I)

\tkzLabelPoints[left,above](R)
\tkzLabelPoints[left,below](I)
\tkzLabelPoints[right](O)
\tkzLabelPoint[left](Origin){$P$}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: just add `->`  , `\tkzDrawSegments[->,thick,black,add = 0 and .4](O,R O,I)`

Comment: and how to draw that two segments between PR and PI. Further how can i increase the size of the top of ray.

Comment: `\tkzDrawSegments[thick,red](Origin,R Origin,I)`

Comment: To mark right angles at the points of tangency, use `\tkzMarkRightAngle(O,R,P)` and `\tkzMarkRightAngle(O,I,P)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here your code with the previous observations, for arrows customization you can take advantage of `arrows.meta` library

**Code**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\Huge
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8,> = {Stealth[length=10pt, inset=5pt]}]]


\tkzDefPoint(0,0){Origin}
\tkzDefPoint(12,0){O}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Radius}{4}

\tkzTangent[from with R = O](Origin,\Radius cm)  \tkzGetPoints{R}{I} 

\tkzDrawCircle[R](Origin,\Radius cm)

\tkzDrawSegments[->,thick,black,add = 0 and .4](O,R O,I)
\tkzDrawSegments[thick,red](Origin,R Origin,I)

\tkzLabelPoints[left,above](R)
\tkzLabelPoints[left,below](I)
\tkzLabelPoints[right](O)
\tkzLabelPoint[left](Origin){$P$}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]