# How to fill space between dotted lines in tikz picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections, fillbetween, fill

I'm trying to fill an area between two dotted lines. I tried a lot of options, but none of them seem to work.

[image: Plot of my current Code]

I labeled the areas I need with the specific colors to fill. My current code is:

```
    \documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage[centering,includeheadfoot,top=25mm, left=40mm, right=25mm, bottom=30mm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage{thmbox}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
    \usetikzlibrary{intersections}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \fill[color=yellow] (0, 0) circle (2); % Sonne im Ursprung (0, 0)
    \shade[right color=lightgray] (7.5, 0) circle (0.5); % Sonne im Ursprung (5, 0)
    \shade[shading=ball, ball color=blue] (10, 0) circle (1); % Erde im Ursprung (10, 0)

    \draw[dashed, color=red ,shorten >=-1.6cm,shorten <=-0cm,name path = A] (0, 2) --node[near start,sloped,above]{\textcolor{red}{Randstrahl}} (7.5, 0.5);
    \draw[dashed, color=red ,shorten >=-3cm,shorten <=-0cm] (0, 2) -- (7.5, -0.5);

    \draw[dashed, color=red ,shorten >=-1.6cm,shorten <=-0cm,name path = B] (0, -2) -- (7.5, -0.5);
    \draw[dashed, color=red ,shorten >=-3cm,shorten <=-0cm] (0, -2) -- (7.5, 0.5);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As mentioned, I tried a lot of options. So this is, more or less, a desperate attempt to solve my problem.

Comment: Welcome @DonFangzahn to Tex.SE

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! The reason why you cannot really fill the regions between the paths in your picture is that you used `shorten >=...` with some negative dimensions. Hence the paths are shorter than the dashed lines. I fixed that to make it work. And even though you could do that with the pgfplots library `fillbetween`, this is not necessary here since you only have straight lines. And I used `backgrounds` and slightly changed the order in which things get drawn in order not to overwrite your planets.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \fill[color=yellow] (0, 0) circle (2); % Sonne im Ursprung (0, 0)
 \shade[right color=lightgray] (7.5, 0) circle (0.5); % Sonne im Ursprung (5, 0)

 \draw[dashed, color=red,name path = A] (0, 2) --
 node[near start,sloped,above]{\textcolor{red}{Randstrahl}} (10, 0)
 coordinate (X1);
 \draw[dashed, color=red ,name path = C] (0, 2) -- 
 (10, -1.33)
 coordinate (X2);

 \draw[dashed, color=red ,name path = B] (0, -2) -- (10, 0)
 coordinate (X3);
 \draw[dashed, color=red ,name path = D] (0, -2) -- (10, 1.33)
 coordinate (X4);
 \begin{scope}[on background layer]
  \fill[gray,
         name intersections={of=A and D,by=X5}] (X3) -- (X5) -- (X4);
  \fill[gray,
         name intersections={of=C and B,by=X6}] (X1) -- (X6) -- (X2);
  \fill[black] (X6) -- (X3) -- (X5);
 \end{scope}
 \shade[shading=ball, ball color=blue] (10, 0) circle (1); % Erde im Ursprung (10, 0)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a version using tangents, as pioneered by esdd in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/453212/121799) yet with a slightly different implementation/ Specifically, I use [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7209/121799) to make the dashed lines tangent to both circles. There are other ways to achieve this, most notably those using the `tkz-euclide` library, see e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/103774/121799). This solution finds the intersections without the intersection library, which works fine for straight lines.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\rsun}{2}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\rmoon}{0.5}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\mid}{\rsun/(\rsun + \rmoon)}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\out}{\rsun/(\rsun - \rmoon)}
 \node[circle,draw,inner color=yellow,outer color=orange!50!yellow,minimum
 size=2*\rsun*1cm,alias=c1] (Sonne) at (0, 0){}; % Sonne 
 \node[left color=lightgray,right color=darkgray,circle,draw,minimum
 size=2*\rmoon*1cm,alias=c2] (Mond) at (7.5, 0){}; % Mond
 % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7209/121799
 \path (Sonne.center) -- coordinate[pos=\mid] (mid) (Mond.center);
 \path (Sonne.center) -- coordinate[pos=\out] (out) (Mond.center);
 \coordinate (Erdmittelpunkt) at (10,0);
 \coordinate (Nordpol) at (10,1);
 \foreach \i in {Sonne,Mond}
 \foreach \j in {1,2}
 \foreach \k in {mid,out}
 \coordinate (\i-\k-\j) at (tangent cs:node=\i,point={(\k)},solution=\j);
 \draw[dashed, color=red] (Sonne-mid-1) -- 
 (intersection cs:first line={(Sonne-mid-1)--(Mond-out-1)}, 
 second line={(Erdmittelpunkt)--(Nordpol)}) coordinate (aux1);
 \draw[dashed, color=red] (Sonne-mid-2) -- 
 (intersection cs:first line={(Sonne-mid-2)--(Mond-out-2)}, 
 second line={(Erdmittelpunkt)--(Nordpol)}) coordinate (aux2);
 \draw[dashed, color=red] (Sonne-out-1) -- 
 (intersection cs:first line={(Sonne-out-1)--(Mond-mid-1)}, 
 second line={(Erdmittelpunkt)--(Nordpol)}) coordinate (Oberhalb);
 \draw[dashed, color=red] (Sonne-out-2) -- 
 (intersection cs:first line={(Sonne-out-2)--(Mond-mid-2)}, 
 second line={(Erdmittelpunkt)--(Nordpol)}) coordinate (Unterhalb);
 % auxiliary coordinates
 \path(intersection cs:first line={(Sonne-mid-1) --(aux1)}, 
 second line={(Sonne-out-2)--(Unterhalb)}) coordinate (Mond1);
 \path(intersection cs:first line={(Sonne-mid-2) --(aux2)}, 
 second line={(Sonne-out-1)--(Oberhalb)}) coordinate (Mond2);
 % fills on background in order not to distort Sonne' nor the tangents
 \begin{scope}[on background layer]
  \fill[gray] (Unterhalb) -- (Mond1) -- (aux1);
  \fill[gray] (Oberhalb) -- (Mond2) -- (aux2);
  \fill[black] (Mond1) -- (aux1) -- (aux2) -- (Mond2);
 \end{scope}
 \shade[shading=ball, ball color=blue] (Erdmittelpunkt) circle (1); % Erde im Ursprung (10, 0)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: From the bottom of my heart, thank you, a lot. This solved my problem.

Comment: Done that, of course :)

Answer (score 15):

Just for fun and learn, an option using `let` to calculate the angle of the shadow lines to draw from the top and bottom of the sun to certain distance to the planet `(0,2) -- +(-\n1:9.5)`, then save this coordinate as `coordinate (a)` and the other from `(0,-2) -- +(\n1:9.5)` save as `coordinate (b)` to draw easily the shadow using the coordinates of the moon, also to put the shadow on the planet with the coordinate in the middle of A and B; the same process is done for the second shadow.

To add more details, I change the background to black in a clipped canvas and I added some stars using foreach instruction, then drawing the moon using clip inside scope to shade the moon using multiple eliptical shapes with decoration to get irregular shades; for the planet another clip scoped shading with another group of ellipses; finally I added a node with `CountriesOfEurope` in this case Greece to draw the ground that I once saw in the catalog of latex symbols.

RESULT:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=0pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[scaled]{CountriesOfEurope}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
    \pagecolor{black}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \clip (-3.5,-3.5) rectangle ++(18,7);
    \shade[inner color=orange!90!black, outer color=black!80!orange] (0,0) circle (18);% Heliosphere 
    \foreach \i in {1,...,500} {\fill[white](-3.5,-3.5)++ (rnd*18cm, rnd*7cm) circle (0.45pt);}
    \shade[inner color=orange!50!yellow, outer color=yellow!50!white] (0,0) circle (2);% Sun

    \begin{scope}
    \clip (7.5,0) circle (0.5); % The moon
    \foreach \j [evaluate=\j as \jn using {\j*5}] in {1,...,20}{
    \fill[white!\jn!black,decoration=random steps, segment length=1pt,decorate](8-0.05*\j,0) circle (0.2 and 0.5);
    }
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}
    \clip (10, 0) circle (1); % The Planet
    \foreach \j [evaluate=\j as \jn using {\j*5}] in {1,...,20}{
    \fill[cyan!\jn!black](11-0.12*\j,0) circle (0.4 and 1);
    }
    \node[text opacity=0.2] at (10,0){\color{white}\EUCountry{143}};
    \end{scope}

    \draw[dashed,line width=0.5pt,white]
    let
        \n1 = {atan(1.5/7.5)}, % atan(sun_rad-Moon_rad/distance_moon_sun)
        \n2 = {atan(2.5/7.5)}% atan(sun_rad+Moon_rad/distance_moon_sun)
    in
    (0,2) -- +(-\n1:9.5) coordinate (a)node[near start,sloped,above]{\color{white}Randstrahl}
    (0,-2) -- +(\n1:9.5) coordinate (b)
    (0,2) -- +(-\n2:15) coordinate (c)
    (0,-2) -- +(\n2:15) coordinate (d);
    \fill[black,fill opacity=0.1] (7.5,0.5) -- ++(0,-1) -- (c) -- (d)-- cycle;
    \fill[black,fill opacity=0.2] (7.5,0.5) -- ++(0,-1) -- (b) -- (a) node[midway](moon-shadow){}-- cycle
    (moon-shadow) circle (0.08 and 0.15);
    \fill[black,fill opacity=0.2](moon-shadow) circle (0.08 and 0.15);

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: This is a really nice piece of artwork! Note, however, that `calc` is not really need here. As far as I can see, all you do with it is to compute two `atan`s of some ratios of known constants. You could do that with `\pgfmathsetmacro`, too. On the other hand, `calc` would be needed if the arguments of the `atan`s were some quantities derived from coordinates. E.g. if you gave the centers of the Sun and Moon the names `Sun` and `Moon`, you could use `... let \p1=($(Sun)-(Moon)$), \n1 = {atan(1.5/veclen(\x1,\y1))}, ...` such that the user could just move them around and things still work.

Comment: +50 for the creative idea to use Greek to draw planets!

Answer (score 8):

Here is another suggestion using nodes instead circles and the `tangent cs`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand\winkel{75}

\path[nodes={circle,outer sep=0pt}]
  (0,0) node(sonne)[fill=yellow,minimum size=4cm]{}
  (sonne.\winkel) coordinate(sonne1)
  ([rotate around={-2*\winkel:(sonne.center)}]sonne.\winkel) coordinate(sonne2)
  (7.5,0) node(mond)[shade,left color=orange!30,right color=brown!80!lightgray,minimum size=1cm]{}
;

\draw[dashed,red,thick]
  (sonne1)
    -- (tangent cs:node=mond,point={(sonne1)},solution=1) coordinate(s11)
    -- ([turn=0]2.8,0) coordinate(r11)
  (sonne1)
    -- node [near start,sloped,above]{Randstrahl}
       (tangent cs:node=mond,point={(sonne1)},solution=2) coordinate(s12)
    -- ([turn=0]2,0) coordinate(r12)
  (sonne2)
    -- (tangent cs:node=mond,point={(sonne2)},solution=1) coordinate(s21)
    -- ([turn=0]2,0)coordinate(r21)
  (sonne2)
    -- (tangent cs:node=mond,point={(sonne2)},solution=2) coordinate(s22)
    -- ([turn=0]2.8,0) coordinate(r22)
;

\path (10,0) node[circle,shading=ball, ball color=blue,minimum size=2cm]{};

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
  \fill[gray!80] (s11) -- (s22) -- (r22) -- (r11) -- cycle;
  \fill[black] (s12) -- (s21) -- (r21) -- (r12) -- cycle;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

But I would change `\winkel` in the code above to eg 75.

Result with `\newcommand\winkel{75}`:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the two solutions already given by @marmot and @esdd, it is possible to use the `calc` library to define the peripheral radii beyond the blue ball.

Note: I removed the loading of the `inputenc` package because it is now included in the LaTeX kernel.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[color=yellow] (0, 0) circle (2); % Sonne im Ursprung (0, 0)
    \coordinate(o') at (7.5,.5);
    \coordinate(o) at (7.5,-.5);
    \draw[ dashed,red]($(7.5,-0.5)!-.4!(0,2)$)coordinate(a)-- (0, 2) --node[near start,sloped,above]{\textcolor{red}{Randstrahl}} ($(0,2)!1.4!(7.5,0.5)$)coordinate(a');
    \draw[dashed,red]($(7.5,-.5)!-.4!(0,-2)$)coordinate(b)-- (0, -2) -- ($(0,-2)!1.4!(7.5, 0.5)$)coordinate(b');
    \begin{scope}
    \clip(7.5,-1.5)rectangle(10,1.5);
    \fill[gray](a')--(o')--(b');
     \fill[gray](a)--(o)--(b);
     \fill(a')--(o')--(o)--(b);
    \end{scope}
    \shade[right color=lightgray] (7.5, 0) circle (0.5); % Sonne im Ursprung (5, 0)
    \shade[shading=ball, ball color=blue] (10, 0) circle (1); % Erde im Ursprung (10, 0)
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: rayon]